# assignment of two QObject

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, copy-constructor, qobject

i have two class names "mamad" and "student" and both of them are inherit from my class "Base"
that "Base" inherit from QObject

in Student Class i have a field : "subject" that is a mamad 
and i have a function (setsubject) that take a newsubject and copy newsubject to subject.

but i have an error :

```
"QObject& Qobject::operator=(const QObject)" is private !
"within this context"
```

how can i fix it?

this is my mamad class :

```
class mamad:public Base
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(int id2 READ getId2 WRITE setId2)
   Q_PROPERTY(QString Name2 READ getName2 WRITE setName2)
public:
    mamad(Base* parent=0);
    int getId2() const { return id2; }
    void setId2(int newId) { id2 = newId; }
    QString getName2() const { return Name2; }

    void setName2(const QString &newName) { Name2 = newName; }
private:
    int id2;
    QString Name2;

};
```

and it is my student class:

```
class student : public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT // Q_OBJECT macro will take care of generating proper metaObject for your class
    Q_PROPERTY(int id READ getId WRITE setId)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString Name READ getName WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(mamad subject  WRITE setsubject)

public:
    student(Base * parent=0);
    int getId() const { return id; }
    void setId(int newId) { id = newId; }
    QString getName() const { return Name; }
    void setName(const QString &newName) { Name = newName; }
   // mamad getsubject()const {return subject;}
    void setsubject( mamad newsubject) {subject=newsubject; }


private:
    int id;
    QString Name;
    mamad subject;
};
```

and i must say that i had this problem with getsubject function too , and i don't know how to fix it.?

please , please, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `QObject`s are not meant to be copied by default. Perhaps you better write a `copy` function which copies just exactly what parameters you need from `newsubject` to `subject`

Edit: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652504/how-do-i-copy-object-in-qt) (possible duplicate) expains more, and says you are meant to only store and copy pointers to `QObject`s and not the objects themselves.

for e.g - very basic and using raw pointers. Recommended to use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) based on requirement

```
class student : public Base
{
    ...
    void setsubject( mamad* newsubject) {subject=newsubject; }
    ...
    mamad* subject;
};

stud.setsubject(&mamadObj);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer  , but can you tell me an example for that (pointers) ? Merci .

Comment: @ErfanTavakoli I have no idea of qt itself, but i have added a basic example of using it with [pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Answer (score 1):

`QObject` can **not** be copied as it says clearly in [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor) and in the error message.

You will have to use `setsubject` as a clone method i.e. duplicate the state by manually copying the fields between the `mamad`s.