# Convert const QObject* to QObject*

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, constants, qobject

I am quite new to Qt. Let MyClass be a sub-class of QObject.

Is there a way to convert properly a `const MyClass *` object to a `MyClass *` object?

I wanted to create a constructor `MyClass(const MyClass *object);` but it doesn't seem to be recommended.

Comment: Why can't you create the constructor? (BTW the constructor syntax doesn't have a return type).

Comment: I read somewhere that the QOject class does not support copies.

Comment: I see. But how is that related to your `const QObject*` to `QObject*` conversion question?

Comment: I have no idea :)
So you think this is the best way to proceed?

Comment: No idea, your question doesn't make much sense!

Comment: What is MyClass(const MyClass*) supposed to do? If the argument is a parent, that won't work. And first passing a const object and the casting away the const-ness seems daft.

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy constructor? That syntax is MyClass(const MyClass& object)

Comment: @cppguy Yes this is what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: I found another thread [dealing with copy constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652584/902025). It seems to be impossible when inheriting QObject...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code :

```
 MyClass *objRef = const_cast<MyClass *>(obj);
```

Comment: Please don't, unless you're 100% sure that ˋobjˋ will never be an actual ˋconstˋ object.