# calling default (implicit) copy constructor from the defined copy constructor

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

I have read many threads regarding this, but I couldn't find an answer to this

In my Qt application, I am using [QSignalSpy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html) to catch a signal. It has a user-defined datatype for one of its parameters. To catch such a parameter, I have to first register that datatype with Qt using [QMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) and using the macro [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE). It says

> This macro makes the type Type known to QMetaType as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in QVariant.

**The problem**: I have a class CustomData with only constructor defined. Now unless I explicitly declare a destructor and a copy constructor, Qt throws an error. I want to use the implicit destructor and copy constructor that C++ gives. For destructor, I used

```
~CustomData() = default;
```

which uses the default destructor. But I cannot use a similar statement for the copy constructor. Will using

```
CustomData( const CustomData& ) {};
```

invoke the implicit copy constructor?

(I am doing this because I want to retain the behavior of the implicit copy constructor)
Thanks in advance.

The CustomData class is shown below

```
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QString>

class CustomData : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  CustomData(QObject *parent = NULL);
  ~CustomData() = default; // I added this line
  //Will the next line call the implicit copy constructor?
  CustomData(const CustomData&) {}; //I added this line


  enum CustomMode {mode1, mode2, mode3};

  void somePublicMethod();

signals:
  void completed(CustomData *data);

private slots:
  void customComplete();

private:
  CustomMode _mode;
  QString _path;

  CustomData *_chained;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomData)
```

Comment: What do you mean, cant you do `CustomData(const CustomData&) = default;`? Why can't you do that? Do you mean that the *editor* gives you an error, or the *compiler* when you build?

Comment: take a look at this thread -- (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810163/c-implicit-copy-constructor-for-a-class-that-contains-other-objects)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , using that code, qt throws an error which is the same error when I dont declare any copy constructor

Comment: When you say "qt throws an error", what do you mean by that? Because that is how you tell the compiler to use the default compiler-generated copy constructor. Do you mean that your editor or IDE says it's wrong? Do you mean you get an error when actually building? Can you tell us *what* error you get?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg -- I get a build error--- synthesized method ‘CustomData::CustomData(const CustomData&)’ first required here 
             return new T(*static_cast<const T*>(t))

Comment: `QObject` is non copyable so I guess the default copy constructor cannot be generated. What invokes copying of this object? The signal in your code uses a pointer. Anyhow, if QT still passes it by value somewhere, maybe pass the data around as `std::unique_ptr<CustomData>` ?

Comment: @clearScreen you should really use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomData*)` instead of `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomData)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the given code compiles without errors on Visual Studio 2013. However if the signature of the signal is changed to `void completed(CustomData data);` then a similar error occurs. Since you have not specified the compiler, but I assume it is gcc/clang you could get the error because template handling differs a bit. If so, the error is most likely caused by `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomData)` since it tries to generate the copy constructor inside. Change it to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomData*)` (because that is what you really need, you are queuing arguments of type `CustomData*` not `CustomData`, at least in the given sample) and if you really have no signals that send the `CustomData` instances by value you should be fine.

Also, if you are passing the object by pointer then you should use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomData*)`. But I'd advise passing it through a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

In short - it doesn't matter. Your implementation does not(hopefully) cause any effect.

If you go through the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator), it says as follows

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator. This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private.

Go through this -- [Q_DISABLE_COPY()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_DISABLE_COPY).

This dictates that you use pointers to do the work. Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652504/how-do-i-copy-object-in-qt) which discusses on how to copy object in Qt.

Comment: But OP has even given an error where copy constructor is instantiated - `new T(*static_cast<const T*>(t))`. So the phrase " I believe you won't find an instance where the code employs the use of copy constructor" is kind of useless.