# Use of temporal constructors inside vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I cam from programming in Java and I thought doing as here [my code] could work the definition of temporal constructors, but I am having problems the proper way of writing the code to just work.

PROBLEM: I want to add a Constructor of the class `Coomunication` for every port I find in a machine and save it into a vector:

ControlCommunication.cpp:

```
...
QVector<Comunication *> ports;
...
void ControlCommunication::checkPorts(){
  qint16  vendorid = cuquito.getVendorID();
  qint16 productid = cuquito.getProductID();
  const QString blankString = "N/A";

  for (const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo : QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
    Comunication com(serialPortInfo.portName());
    addPort(com); // <- I do not know how to get this working well

  }
}
```

ControlCommunication.h:

```
class ControlCommunication : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit ControlCommunication(QObject *parent = nullptr);
  QVector<Comunication*> getComunicationPorts(){return comunicationports;}
  void addPort(Comunication com);
...
```

Comunication.h:

```
#ifndef COMUNICATION_H
#define COMUNICATION_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QMainWindow>

class Comunication:public QObject{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Comunication( QString serialPortName);
  Comunication();

public:

public slots:
  void openSerialPort();
  void closeSerialPort();
  void writeData(const QByteArray &data);
  void readData(QByteArray &data);
  void handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error);
  QString getPortName(){return portname;};
signals:

private:
  QSerialPort *m_serial = nullptr;
  QString portname;
};

#endif // COMUNICATION_H
```

The error I get is: *call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Comunication'
comunication.h:8:20: note: copy constructor of 'Comunication' is implicitly deleted because base class 'QObject' has a deleted copy constructor
qobject.h:449:20: note: 'QObject' has been explicitly marked deleted here
controlcommunication.cpp:27:49: note: passing argument to parameter 'com' here*

As I understand from the error message, I cannot call a constructor which is gonna be deleted in that function from other statements. How can i get this working?

Comment: What are you calling a "temporal constructor"?

Comment: Do you mean a "copy constructor?"

Comment: Does inheritance from `QObject` actually needed?

Comment: Your understanding of the error is incorrect. The error says you're trying to copy a QObject. That's [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652584/7427152).

Comment: Yes, I need the inheritance from QObject to call signals and slots between classes

Comment: Can you show "communication.h" as well?

Comment: Maybe try changing the `addPort` function to pass a pointer or reference to Comunication instead of passing by value.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting mean you can't copy `Communication`. When you're passing `com` to `addPort`, you're making a copy of the object which will be passed to the function. But because you're inheriting a `QObject` you can't make copies of your objects. Which means you can't those objects by value. You can add pointers or (ideally) a reference to use objects.

But in your case, I don't think that's going to work easily, you seem to want a `QVector<Communication*>` which I'm assuming will be filled by `addPort`. But you're creating `Communication` in your loop which will be delted when it exists the loop, and so pointers to it won't work.

I don't have enough information, and I'm not versed with Qt, so please someone correct if I'm wrong, but I would suggest that you build `Communication` inside `addPort` and change `QVector<Communication*>` to `QVector<Communication>`.

My intuition would be that `Communication` doesn't need to inherit from `QObject`, but I could be wrong. But the data from your program should probably be separated from the Qt stuff, to make things easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the Comunication object by value into the `addPort` function. This will try to create a copy of the object. But QObjects (and anything derived from QObject) are non-copyable. So you should change your function to take a pointer or reference instead.

Also, you probably need to allocate your objects on the heap because they will go out of scope, freeing any stack memory.

```
void addPort(Communication *com);

...

  for (const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo : QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {

    // Allocate on the heap
    Comunication *com = new Comunication(serialPortInfo.portName());

    // Pass pointer to addPort
    addPort(com);

  }
```

Comment: Sure. See [QSharedPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html), etc.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes it support it, but it has its own ownership policy: to most classes, you might pass `parent` which will be the owner of the created instance.